# onCreate() of Launcher activity gets called when app launched on clicking launcher icon

Tags: android, splash-screen, launcher, android-launcher, launchmode

I have found very strange bug with  the Android application, while installing the application in Android Device with given flow.

1. Installed the app from playstore(old version).
2. Launched the application(Now I'm in the HomeScreen,.i.e., `HomeActivity`).
3. Now, I upgraded the app by installing the latest build(under production build, yet to be released to playstore).
4. Click the launcher icon, wait till Home Screen becomes visible and keep the app in the background by pressing menu button.
5. Now, Launch the application by clicking launcher icon.

In this case, Splash Screen(`Activity`) gets launched and then takes me to the home screen. In the logs, call goes to `onStop()` of the HomeActivity. This means Activity is not destroyed. So, When I click launcher icon, it should resume the HomeActivity, instead it recreates the splashActivity. But when i launch the app from background, activity resumes and no splash screen gets displayed. 
Is it a correct behavior? If so, then I'm not getting the callback to `onDestroy()`.

Below is my activity code in the manifest:

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.app.ui.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.app.ui.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I did not set any launch mode to `SplashActivity`. And after some time, it becomes proper and splash screen is not shown.

Also, when i launch the app from background or press back button and then click the app icon, this bug is not reproduced. This happens only when I click launcher icon, keeping app in the background  and after some time, it becomes proper.

Also, when I installed the application without updating, this issue didn't occur. Only when I update the apk, this happens

Why this happens in the initial launches..Is it a bug in the android..?If so, How to avoid this issue..

Answer (score 0):

The reason the app is closed after some time in the background is because your device's kernel is killing the process in order to run more processes in it's place. I am assuming you are accessing other apps while your app is running in the background, and that is why it is getting killed (and therefore skipping the onDestroy() call in the Android lifecycle!).

From the documentation on Android Developer's guide to Activity Lifecycle for onDestroy():

> Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data! For example, if an activity is editing data in a content provider, those edits should be committed in either onPause() or onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), not here. This method is usually implemented to free resources like threads that are associated with an activity, so that a destroyed activity does not leave such things around while the rest of its application is still running. **There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around after the process goes away**.

[Link to documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy())

Comment: ,I thought the same. May be I'm wrong, but this is what I observed. After some time, it works properly. If device kernel is killing the process, then it should kill everytime right..Why only in the initial launches. This is where I'm confused about it.